# Raspberry Pi display all black

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to install Raspbian on Pi 3 but when I connect it to my monitor using Hdmi the screen is just all black and it doesn't say anything. I've tried searching online but all the answers I found I got confused, since most involve connecting using ssh or something while I can't even get it to turn on to connect it to wifi.

Comment: what do the LED indicators do? Do they turn green?

Comment: @BRBonn No it is always red, i have two and the other one is always red also but the display works

Comment: @eyllanesc and others:
I agree that this is off-topic, but why super user? Why not the raspberry pi stack exchange? I move for migrating this to the stack exchange subdomain that is specific to the mentioned hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a flash of green near the power led after you plug in the power, that should indicate its booting up okay. I'd suggest verifying the install on your sd card, flash another card and try that. Ensure the power plug you have is good quality and supplying the correct voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-answer: you might want to verify the install on the SD before spending too much time with blind boots.

Easy answer: use a wired usb adapter (preferably with an alternate source of power), then ssh and run `raspi-config` as I'm sure you've already read.

Moderate answer: stick the SD card in an adapter and edit the `/boot/config.txt` file. See [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/) for syntax.

Advanced: Edit files as in moderate answer above, but this time target crontab to add a script hook that connects to wifi, thus allowing ssh.

Comment: For the install I downloaded NOOBS, formatted the SD card and extracted the NOOBS onto the SD

Comment: @Dan I haven't used NOOBS in a while. Is there not a `verify install` option now?